# Store Encrypted Data in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, encryption

I want to store data in encrypted form in a sendable Data Extension and decrypt it while using.
So basically, my DE will contain SubscriberKeys and EmailAddress. Email Address should be encrypted. But while sending email, I should be able to decrypt it.

Also, after email send, when this information goes to All Subscribers, it should still be in encrypted format.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't encrypt the Email Address field. If you need such a solution, you will need to use [Tokenized Sending](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/marketing_cloud/marketing_cloud_security_and_encryption_products/tokenized_sending/) or [Field Level Encryption](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/marketing_cloud/marketing_cloud_security_and_encryption_products/field_level_encryption/).

With Tokenized Sending, a spoof email address or mobile number is used as a token; e.g. 1234345@memberemail.com which you store in your Sendable DE, then OMM invokes the Resolve Token API to retrieve the actual email address at send time.

Be aware that Tokenized Sending does not work out of the box; you need to build your own tokenized server to align with the [documented methods](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/marketing_cloud/marketing_cloud_security_and_encryption_products/tokenized_sending/creating_your_resolve_token_api___resolve_token_api_specification/) — I've done this and it's pretty straightforward if you have experience in building REST API servers.

Also note that tokenization is enabled for an entire business unit; you can't disable tokenization for some email sends and enable it for others.

Comment: I am new to marketing cloud and I have the same requirement that needs implementation. Could you please guide me how/what steps need to be taken both in Marketing cloud and source systems? Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Totally Agree with Elliot but Be cautious about the [Limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_unsupported_tokenized_sending_features1.htm&type=5) of using Tokenized Sending as well. You can't use commonly used Journey Builder Activities, Queries, Filters as these features require data to be stored in It's original state in SFMC and Currently I am not aware of any Solution or workaround to overcome these Unsupported features while using tokenization

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend purchasing SF Shield platform encryption which does what you need for enterprise level. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_overview.htm&type=0

Comment: The shield platform isn't enabled on Marketing Cloud https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_considerations_apps.htm&type=5